# Cross reference list of file names to sql query column to find differences

Tags: sql, file, exists, file-exists

I am trying to cross reference a list of files to a column return on a select query. I have an sql query that returns a list of part numbers and a list of files in a folder that are named for the part number they are created for. I need to use the list of part numbers from the sql query to find what parts are in the query and not in the list of files. This will allow me to see what part programs have yet to be created.

Is there a simple way to do this with a select query? I saw a post online about detecting files with an exist statement but I did not see anything about cross referencing it to a column list.

I want to know if I can use this type of code:

```
 Create FUNCTION dbo.fc_FileExists(@path varchar(8000))
 RETURNS BIT
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @result INT
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result, OUTPUT
 RETURN cast(@result as bit)
 END;
 GO
```

The code above is an example of what I am looking for, however instead of declaring the @path I want to return an entire column.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh The query to select parts is protected by company privacy contracts and is honestly too long to post. I will post a generic form of what I am looking for though.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time!